# Changing the numberings of nested lists in an Enumerate environment, in LaTeX

Tags: latex, enumerate

I want to produce the following in LaTeX:

```
1. Item
    2. Item
    3a. Item
    3b. Item
    4. Item
5. Item
```

Basically I have already tried using nested `enumerate` environments, but I have a problem with implementing the different numberings.

How can I do the above in LaTeX?

Comment: I'm sorry, but does your indentation correspond to the level of the nested enumerate environments that you want?

Comment: This should be moved to tex.stackexchange.com...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of the `{enumerate}` environment is to number things algorithmically.  If you really want the numbers to appear as shown in your question, I can't identify what algorithm you want to be used.  For the example you show, I think the easiest method is just to program the labels yourself instead of trying to program LaTeX to do it.  I would just do it this way:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[1.]  Item
   \begin{itemize}
    \item[2.  ] Item
    \item[3a. ] Item
    \item[3b. ] Item
    \item[4.  ] Item
   \end{itemize}
\item [5. ] Item
\end{itemize}
```

With LaTeX, the quickest path to a solution often involves brute force :-)

Comment: "With LaTeX, the quickest path to a solution often involves brute force :-)" - I love you.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\addtocounter{enumi}{1}\arabic{enumi}}
%% Second list uses first counter

\def\startenumtuple{\setcounter{enumii}{1}\addtocounter{enumi}{1}
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}}
\def\endenumtuple{
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\addtocounter{enumi}{1}\arabic{enumi}}}

\noindent Here's my list:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item
\startenumtuple
\item Item
\item Item
\endenumtuple
\item Item
\item Item
\end{enumerate}
\item Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

(Mica's version was used in the first iteration of this code)

The right way involves defining environments based on enumerate that do the right thing with the counters: the above code would need tweaking to get it to work right if you wanted to change the nesting of the list environments.

Answer (score 1):

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Roman{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\Roman{enumi}. \alph{enumii}}

\noindent Here's my list:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1.
\begin{enumerate}
\item List 2, Item 1
\item List 2, Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\item Item 2.
\item Item 3.
\end{enumerate}
```

Then change the `\Roman` in the `renewcommand` to whatever you want it to be: `\alph` or `\arabic`

Comment: +1: It doesn't really answer the question -there should be a second env that reuses the first counter, and the innermost env should be indented as this second env, but I based my code on it, so it was useful to me.